# power query connect db2

Tags: excel, db2, powerquery

I try to use power query to connect the db2 , but there is no option for db2 connection,
[image]

can someone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My office edition is standard 2013 , which is not supported for import data from other database.

Answer (score 0):

did you update your powerquery ? I have this option in Excel 2013.

the current version is : 2.44.4675.281

[image]

[Download PowerQuery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379)